# How to print the timestamp of date in a Views fields?

Tags: views, datetime, importing-exporting

I am using the [Views Data Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module to show feeds as XML.
I need to show the created date and updated date in timestamp .

How can I implement it?

Answer (score 10):

There is a way:

1. Go to Configuration > Regional and language > Date and Time > Formats (Tab)
2. Then click "add format" to add a new date format and just type "U" in the textfield. The "U" is actually the timestamp.
3. Go back to "Types" tab and add the new date type you just created and give it some name like "Timestamp".
4. In your view select your date field and select your custom date type in "Choose how users view dates and times"

Hope this is what you were searching for.

Otherwise: If you just look for the MySQL like timestamp just select "Plain" as the formatter in your views field.